# .htaccess complex mod_rewrite rule, language in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to write a rule, that would redirect URL like this:

```
myweb.com/en/page
```

to

```
myweb.com/page.php?lang=en
```

And URL like this

```
myweb.com/en/page/SOME_TEXT(EVEN WITH SLASHES)
```

to

```
myweb.com/page.php?lang=en&string=SOME_TEXT
```

This code:

```
RewriteRule ^(cz|en)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

works for the language but not for the another text (SOME_TEXT).

What should I change? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteRule ^/?(cz|en)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$  $2.php?lang=$1&string=$3 [QSA,L]
```

<del>?: is used to disable the capture group, so $1 now Contains the value of your second capture group.</del>

Comment: I get error 404 on both addresses (with some text and wihout text too).

Comment: Now both URLs works, but for the URL with text, string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/(cz|en)/(.*)$  $2.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(cz|en)/([^/]+)/(.*)$  $2.php?lang=$1&string=$3 [L]
```

Comment: I get error 404 on both addresses (with some text and wihout text too).

Comment: @PavelStraka Please try this order and let me know

Comment: Now I get 404 just for the URL with some text. Shorter URL is ok.

Comment: @PavelStraka Please try this order and let me know